# ¿Por qué me aparecen las etiquetas del eje y divididas (representadas) en dos números?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy tratando de terminar un proyecto en el que he empleado el paquete tkinter de Python. Uno de los gráficos no me muestra el valor de frecuencias completo en el eje, que es lo que me gustaría, sino que utiliza una especie de notación científica. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código para que podamos ver que ocurre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib formatea por defecto las etiquetas numéricas cuando los números son muy grandes o pequeños (muchos dígitos) para facilitar la legibilidad y evitar que las etiquetas consuman demasiado espacio. Para ello combina la notación científica, como un multiplicador en potencias base 10, con un concepto conocido como offset (compensación), el cuál que se usa en tu caso:

> +1.08e5

esto es:

> +1.08x10<sup>5</sup>

y significa que el valor real de cada etiqueta del eje <kbd>y</kbd> es el resultado de sumar (por eso el **`+`** delante) a cada una el offset, por ejemplo, para 82.5:

> 82.5 + 1.08x10<sup>5</sup> = 108082.5

Si quieres evitar esto, debes desactivar tanto la notación científica como el offset, lo cual puedes hacer con el método [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

**`# Con offset (por defecto)`**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


freqs = [108082,  108077,  108075,  108073,  108070, 108065]
samples = range(6)

plt.plot(samples, freqs)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`# Sin offset`**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


freqs = [108082,  108077,  108075,  108073,  108070, 108065]
samples = range(6)

plt.plot(samples, freqs)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')  # <<<<<<<<<<
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]